# Configuration synchronization page throwing 504 timeout error

Tags: configuration, 9

This issue is happening on every level above my vagrant local box. It's a brand new website and a few days back I had to copy my database from local to staging environment. Once done, I ran drush -cim to import the files from config/sync directory into the database.

no error while running the drush -cim command and also all the UUIDs match from local to staging environment. However, on loading the config/sync page in the front end, I constantly see 504 timeout error. Screenshot as below:

[image]

The watchdog does not have any error and I saw just one error message:

[image]

This error is not constant and I am unable to reproduce this error as well. any help on how I can bring the config/sync page back up??

Comment: A 504 is a server error, not thrown by Drupal - you'll need to to dig through your server logs to find the issue

Comment: Understood. Server log means Apache log right?

Comment: Probably yes, but it depends on your setup. If you've got varnish for example check its logs, if you're using PHP FPM check those logs, and so on

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. This doesn't have anything to do with config files UUIDs right?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, not directly anyway. Stuff like this usually comes down to server config or resource/memory problems in my experience

Comment: ok i'll check server logs

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got this fixed. Apache log did not have any evidence for this issue. However, on the config/sync page in the 'Import' tab, I saw an error as "/var/www/html/config/sync" folder is not writable. Making this folder permission to 760 fixed the issue for me.